# Reflection Method to get com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService methods

Tags: java, android

I tried to access `NotificationManagerService` class which is in `android.service.notification` package using reflection method. I tried this to clear Notifications of other apps which has `FLAG_NO_CLEAR`

Here is the snippet,

```
 try {
      Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService");
      Constructor<?> constructor = c.getDeclaredConstructor();
      constructor.setAccessible(true);
      Object o = constructor.newInstance();
      Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("cancelAllNotificationsInt",
                     new Class[]{String.class,int.class,int.class,boolean.class});
      method.setAccessible(true);
      Object r = method.invoke(o,sbn.getPackageName(), Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR,0,true);
      if((boolean)r)
          Log.d("Working","yes");
  } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

But I am getting exception,

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService

The class exist and [here is the link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java?autodive=0%2F%2F) from where I confirmed it.

Help me!!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using **Reflection** and trying to assess **Framework class** is not a good way of implementing a feature. This is a bad practice.

From Android 4.3 onward, you can now cancel notifications from any apps.

You just need to implement the [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

you could cancel the notification of any app using the method `NotificationListenerService.cancelNotification(String pkg, String tag, int id)`

you could refer this sample [notification-listener-service-example](https://github.com/Chagall/notification-listener-service-example)

Comment: But It does not cancel if the notification is not clearable(`sbn.isClearable() --> false`). That is  why I am trying this

Comment: If Android Framework does not provide you a provision to cancel notification which is not clear-able, then does that means you should override it and do it ? . I think that is not what android guidelines specify you to do

Comment: I just tried to call that private method which will do want I want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very particular with android development but this is usually environment issue. Sometimes, the actual class is not there in the library depending on how you have included your dependencies.

- If at your development / IDE, you already encounter the problem, go to your external libraries imported by your gradle (or maven). Drill down to com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService if it is there. Or debug it and see if `Class<?> c` is null.
- If it happened on the deployed version, open the file, go to the imported classes and drill down to the actual class if it is there or not.
- If this library is provided by the environment you deploy - might be (1) overwritten by other library conflict or (2) version issue

Comment: Thanks! I will check it